# Using a large number of concurrent SwingWorkers

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, swingworker

I'm trying to using a large number of SwingWorkers (~100). I have a class

```
Creature extends SwingWorker<Creature, Point>
```

and I want to have each instantiation to move around independently at the same time. I'm using SwingWorker since the position of each instantiation is represented in a GUI and is constantly updated. At the moment, only 10 will move and the others will not, since [the max thread limit of SwingWorker is 10.](http://www.jroller.com/ethdsy/entry/swingworker_is_not_a_thread) The suggestion of the linked article is to put each SwingWorker in its own thread, since they implement Runnable and will allow one to bypass that limit.

I have attempted to do this but nothing shows up, so clearly I've messed it up. How do I increase the number of avaliable SwingWorkers (using the method specificed in the article or otherwise)?

```
Executor ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
   final Creature c = new Creature(this);
   Thread t = new Thread(c){
      public void run(){
         c.execute();  
      }
   };   
  ex.execute(t);
}
```

Comment: Don't pass Threads to an Executor. pass Runnable instead.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You mean `Runnable t = new Thread(c){...}`? I just tried, it did not work

Comment: I mean don't create a Thread at all.  If this doesn't work you are doing something wrong. `Executor.execute(Runnable)` takes a Runnable.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ah that worked well. Good suggestion. If you stick that in an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you write

```
Executor ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
   final Creature c = new Creature(this);
   ex.execute(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
         c.execute();  
      }
   });   
}
```

Or even change `execute()` to `run()` and make the Creature `Runnable`

```
Executor ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   ex.execute(new Creature(this));
```